# Why is email not being received if it appears to be successfully sent?

Tags: python, smtplib

I cant understand why I'm not receiving email from [this function](https://github.com/metaperl/zeek-autopost/blob/master/python-rewards/pr.py#L108) ... as you can see [the smtp transcript is successful](http://paste.kde.org/524258/)

I switched to using 10minutemail.com to receive email to make sure it wasnt being blocked by a blacklist or something.

I also have been successful in sending plain text using [a script in the same directory](https://github.com/metaperl/zeek-autopost/blob/master/python-rewards/simple_email.py) to the same recipient and from the same sender and it worked fine.

Comment: it seems to be happening only from the program... a command-line script works just fine.

Comment: The transcript shows multiple Mime-Version: headers and other hints that the message was hand crafted. If you send a valid, well-formed message, does that get through?

Comment: The message was not hand-crafted. Python's email module did it, per the source code.

Comment: Well, it is not well-formed. There can only be a single Mime-Version header, one Subject, one From: etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. You have to attach HTML only, otherwise, it will try to render the plain text and not show the html.